# RemoteWebDriver connects successfully in Java but not in C#

Tags: java, c#, selenium-webdriver

I am using RemoteWebDriver to test, when I run the following Java code everything works as it should.

```
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://10.0.1.10:4444"),
            new DesiredCapabilities());
```

When I run the following C# code I get a ClassCastException (Cannot Convert String to Dictionary) from RemoteWebDriver.StartSession()

```
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://10.0.1.10:4444/wd/hub"), 
            new DesiredCapabilities());
```

I've also tried using `DesiredCapabilities.Safari()` with the same result, any ideas what could be going wrong please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a very strange one, the C# implementation of WebDriver seems to be stricter than the Java (and Python) implementation. It seems that the C# implementation check that the HTTP responses have the content type set to JSON, the Java and Python counterparts just try to parse and complain only if there are problems. The id's of the elements need to be formatted as strings else you get another similar exception; again this is not true for the Java and Python implementations and it seems that C# does not allow locating elements using compound class names.

To fix this problem I had to modify the implementation of WebDriver I was using to cater for these differences.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  System.Uri uri = new System.Uri("http://localhost:7055/hub");
  WebDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(uri, DesiredCapabilities.Firefox());
```

or this

```
  System.Uri uri = new System.Uri("http://10.0.1.10:4444/wd/hub");
  WebDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(uri, DesiredCapabilities.Firefox());
```